# Motion layout on swipe is not working I have use tab view with view pager

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout, android-touch-event

I have created a bottom sheet with motion layout having default open 35% and in side that we have tabview and view pager and on Swipe of tabView I want that view pager height gone.
But onSwipe is not working on touch of tab view.
this is my Activity Screen XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_property_map_view_scene"
        tools:context=".maps.MapViewScreen">
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            .......   
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/map_tabs_views_list"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_10"
            android:background="@drawable/white_view_bar_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/map_add_note_btn"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_10"
            android:background="@drawable/white_circle_bg"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/add_note"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map_tabs_views_list"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slide_top"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_100"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_10"
            android:src="@drawable/slide_top"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1" />
    
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/tab_unselect"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/slide_top"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/Theme.MapTabs"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/grey_666666" />
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_0"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_container"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_tabs" >
    
            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/map_tabs_view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                android:visibility="visible"/>
    
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    
    
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />
    
    
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_45"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/touchView"
            android:elevation="@dimen/dim_1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

and here is my layoutDescription file xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="2000"
        motion:motionInterpolator="linear">
<!--        <OnClick motion:clickAction="jumpToEnd" motion:targetId="@+id/map_add_note_btn" />-->
        <OnSwipe motion:touchAnchorId="@id/map_tabs" motion:touchAnchorSide="bottom" motion:dragDirection="dragDown" motion:touchRegionId="@id/map_tabs"/>
       <KeyFrameSet>
       </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>


    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/map_tabs_views_list"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/map_add_note_btn"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/slide_top"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_100"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"

            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_10"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_10" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/map_tabs"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"

            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/slide_top" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_container"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_tabs"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/touchView"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/view_pager_container"/>
        <!--        <Constraint-->
<!--            android:id="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1"-->
<!--            motion:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35"-->
<!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->
<!--        <Constraint-->
<!--            android:id="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_2"-->
<!--            motion:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1"-->
<!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/map_tabs_views_list"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/slide_top"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/map_add_note_btn"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/slide_top"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dim_100"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dim_10"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/map_tabs"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dim_10" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/map_tabs"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_container"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_tabs"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/touchView"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dim_0"
            motion:visibilityMode="ignore"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_tabs_views_list"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        <!--        <Constraint-->
<!--            android:id="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_1"-->
<!--            motion:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/dim_70"-->
<!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->
<!--        <Constraint-->
<!--            android:id="@+id/property_map_view_guide_line_2"-->
<!--            motion:layout_constraintGuide_end="@dimen/dim_70"-->
<!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

swipe is not working on the swipe of tabview.
**Thank you for your time**

Answer (score 0):

Check this class that extends from MotionLayout and intercept the touch when try to swipe from the clickable views, here is the link:

[ChildrenSwipeHandlingMotionLayout](https://gist.github.com/asadmukhtar28/affcf928f9860f44232cc360eaf2ca38)

Replace the parent to ChildrenSwipeHandlingMotionLayout and set the viewPager area in your activity/fragment like this:

```
binding.motionLayoutRoot.viewPagerArea = viewDataBinding.viewPagerMedia
```